# getWindow() is not recognized by AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android

I have constructed a method called `dialogGenerator` that creates and instance `venster` of `AlertDialog.Builder`. The method calls the usual class methods on `venster`, without any problem;

```
public void dialogGenerator (String title, String message){

        final AlertDialog.Builder venster = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        venster.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp);
        venster.setTitle(title);
        venster.setMessage(message);
        venster.setPositiveButton(
                "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }
        );
        venster.show();
    }
```

However, when I add (for making the background transparent);

```
venster.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent)
```

`getWindow()` is not recognized. There is no alt+Enter pop-up that offers a solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is because `AlertDialog.Builder` does not have a window.

I believe you are trying to access the window of the built dialog.

When you call `show()` you should notice that it returns an `AlertDialog` and you should try making your call on that object, rather than the builder object.

```
AlertDialog dialog = venster.show();
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Thanks Quinn, for pointing out I missed the window step. Added your code. Indeed also needed to replace venster.show() with dialog.show().